# Как решить ошибку: No module named 'statsmodels'?

Tags: python

Делаю вот эту команду:

```
import tsfresh
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
No module named 'statsmodels'
```

Когда напрямую импортирую statmodels:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

Та же ошибка:

```
No module named 'statsmodels'
```

Модуль `statmodels` установлен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему эта ошибка может возникать и как ее исправить?

Спасибо

Comment: Иногда бывает что при установке одно имя написано, а при импорте надо другое вписывать. Поищите в интернете программы с этим модулем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти 3 шага решили вопрос:

1. `pip install git+https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels`
2. `pip uninstall patsy`
3. `pip install patsy`

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, у вас установлено несколько версий `Python`. Используйте эу команду для установки модуля и ошибка должна исправиться `python -m pip install statsmodels`

Comment: так я так и устанавливаю этот модуль) ошибка не пропала